# mySQLi and PHP login system with different permissions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm pretty new to PHP and I need to make a login system and I need to check if the user has certain permission, then show something on the page. Let me give a pseudo-code example:

```
IF USER HAS PERMISSION "CONTACTS" OR USER HAS PERMISSION "ALL"
  SHOW CONTACTS LINK
```

I've been using DevDojo's [php login script](https://github.com/thedevdojo/php-login-script), and I wanted something similar or an adaption of that code with a multi-level system.
I've tried many things here on SO but none of them really fit my needs, I need to use something like `if $user->hasPermission("contacts")`. because as I have many features, levels like 1, 2 and etc. won't fit, and admin or not also won't. I'm pretty newbie, so explanation is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know why downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 different levels of user with 3 being the master level...

When the user logs in, set a PHP variable to the permission value set in the database.

Create your template containing all visible content. Decide which sections will be hidden to users at each level and use PHP if statements to prevent blocks being loaded to the page.

A very basic example would be

```
<?php $level=2; ?>

<img src="http://someimg.com/img.jpg" alt="level 1">

<?php if($level >= 2){ ?>
 <img src="http://someimg.com/img.jpg" alt="level 2">
<?php }

if($level == 3){?>
 <img src="http://someimg.com/img.jpg" alt="level 3">
<?php }?>
```

In this example the variable $level represents the user level, this is followed by 3 images. The first image is available to all level users, the second image is available to user level 2 & above and the third is only visible to master level users. You can see the changes when you change "$level=2" to a value of 1 or 3.

Comment: how to create this level in mySQL?

Comment: @MucaP Add a row called level in the database and set it the same as you would the username, password, email address etc.

Comment: And it would recognize the varchar as a number?

Comment: If you want to use varchar, I suppose you can, I'd prefer to set permission values as integers as they take up less space in the database